Create a calculated field with the total of two pivot tables in looker studio
I have created two pivot tables with the information from a google sheet. Now I want to be able to get the percentage between both totals that I have in the pivot table, is there any way to calculate it?
I have read that I would have to create fields calculated from 0 to give me the result I am getting through the pivot but if I calculate it that way when the pivot is updated those changes would be obsolete and I would have to do a manual job again. I have to report this percentage every Monday, how could I calculate it?
Thank you very much!!
